# Can I consider higher order function's a kind of framework in JS?

Tags: javascript, frameworks

Since surfing through some blogs I got to know the difference between library and framework.

So the technical difference lies in the inversion of control.

i.e when the control is not in the hand of developer when and where to invoke a functionality that means we are using a framework.

So, since in higher order function like map, filter and reduce when we pass callbacks then it's not in our hand when and where to invoke that callback.

So, can we say that it is the inversion of control from calling the higher order function (that way in our hand) to calling the callback (which was not in our hand) ?

Can we call that higher order function a framework ?